# .NET 4.5, Entity Framework 6 - Create/Update/Modify/Delete Many to Many

Tags: entity-framework-6

Lets say I have 2 models, PeopleClass, CarsClass, also I am using Lazy Loading. Many 'People' can own the same 'Car'. How do I update the relationship to handle that? Ideally as an Interface, but if I have to do it in a Controller that is fine too.

I am aware there is an .add() and .attach() method, but how do you implement that in a Web API 2 Controller w/ EF using async actions and lazy loading (need to know how to create, add, update/modify, and delete)?

I found this as well and curious as to what ppl think as a solution: http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/

Code Example:

People Class/Model:

```
public class People
    {
        public People()
        {
            this.Cars = new HashSet<Car>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PeopleName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Car Class/Model:

```
public class Car
    {
        public Car()
        {
            this.Peoples = new HashSet<People>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<People> Peoples { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext file:

```
public DbSet<People> Peoples { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
                  .HasMany(c => c.Cars) 
                  .WithMany(t => t.Peoples)
                  .Map(m => { 
                        m.ToTable(“PeopleCars”);
                        m.MapLeftKey(“PeopleId”); 
                        m.MapRightKey(“CarId”); 
              });
}
```

What do I have to do in my async controller using EF w/ actions? I know there are methods called: clear, add, attach find etc. But I am unclear how to implement in GET, POST, PUT, DELETE controller actions.

**UPDATE SINCE INITIAL POST:**

I got PUT to work in my Web API 2 Controller using EF + Async Actions. I just need to know how to do a DELETE now.

```
// PUT: api/People/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> People(int id, People peoples)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != peoples.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var env = db.People
                .Include(p => p.Cars)
                .Single(q => q.Id == peoples.Id);

            db.Entry(env).CurrentValues.SetValues(peoples);

            foreach(var automobile in peoples.Cars)
            {
                db.Cars.Attach(automobile);
                env.Cars.Add(automobile);
            }

            //db.Entry(peoples).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PeopleExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

Comment: I, for one am unclear about what you are asking? Do you want to learn how to perform CRUD operations on your People and Cars tables using EF and Linq ?

Comment: or, do you asking about the Many to Many Table PeopleCars?

Comment: How to manage the many to many relationship that's dictated by the composite keys, as stated in ques, there is add, attach, find methods and i am unsure how to implement.

Comment: I updated my code above, and I got PUT to work in the controller example above. Do you know how to make DELETE work?

Comment: The namings are very confusing. `peoples` - why the plural and not `person`? `env` - is this the db instance of the person? This many confusing names make it difficult to read.
Returning `NotFound` on PUT? If it wasn't found why not just PUT it then? You need a different error there, 409 or 5xx maybe?

Comment: See the example with Remove. http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework/

Comment: SO that doesnt work as its for .NET Core v1

Comment: I am not sure what is so hard about answering this, the QUESTION clearly asks: "What do I have to do in my [async] controller [using EF w/ actions]? I know there are methods called: clear, add, attach find etc. But I am unclear how to implement in GET, POST, PUT, DELETE controller actions."